# SQL request to group and sum numbers by their day of creation

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

Let me explain this. I have a table where I have two important fields I need :
The first one is a double, and the second one is a date.

I would like to make a requests that groups entries by `YYYY-MM-DD`, and adds each field of the double by group.

For example, I have two entries the same day :

```
   |   amount    |    date
1  |    100      | 2010-01-01
2  |    200      | 2010-01-01
```

**What I need is :**

```
1  |     300     | 2010-01-01
```

Is that possible ? For the moment here is my request :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (d) amount, to_char(datecreation, 'YYYY-MM-DD') d
   FROM mytable
  GROUP BY d, amount
  ORDER BY d ASC;
```

*What I get is :*

```
1  | 100   | 2010-01-01
```

It doesn't add the grouped amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(amount), date from mytable group by date order by sum(amount) ASC;
```

If your dates have a time part, then

```
select sum(amount), to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from mytable group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') order by sum(amount) ASC;
```

Comment: The second request worked, thanks a lot ! I'll put as accepted answer as soon as stackoverflow let's me

Comment: If I take it a little further, and want to increment the amount for each day. Let's say I have the following just after previous operation : 
    1  | 300 | 2010-01-01
    2  | 200 | 2010-01-02
Can I get :
    1  | 300 | 2010-01-01
    2  | 500 | 2010-01-02

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amount, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
 ORDER BY SUM(amount) ASC;
```