# SQL query that increments a field by the previous number in that field

Tags: sql, postgresql

First, this was my first question concerning that issue : [SQL request to group and sum numbers by their day of creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775248/sql-request-to-group-and-sum-numbers-by-their-day-of-creation)

Now, imagine I want to make it more complex, after previous operations and thanks to answers, I have results grouped by day, so each entries of the day are added. I have this :

```
1 | 200 | 2010-01-01
2 | 100 | 2010-01-01
```

Transformed into this :

```
1 | 300 | 2010-01-01
```

That's already pretty good, but what if I want the amount field to increment each time ?

```
1 | 300 | 2010-01-01
2 | 200 | 2010-01-02
```

Will become :

```
1 | 300 | 2010-01-01
2 | 500 | 2010-01-02
x | (previous amount + this amount) | this date
```

The sql query I got thanks to answers to my previous question :

```
select sum(amount), to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
from mytable 
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
order by sum(amount) ASC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A running sum can be done using windowing functions:

```
select sum(amount) over (order by date asc), 
       to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
from mytable 
order by date ASC;
```

If you want the running sum over the aggregated result, just put it into a sub-query:

```
select sum(day_total) over (order by date) as running_total,
       day_total, 
       date
from (
  select sum(amount) as day_total, 
         date
  from mytable 
  group by date
) t
order by date
```

If the column `date` is actual of the data type `date`, then there is no reason to use to_char() on it. Btw: it's not a terribly good idea to use reserved words (`date`) for column names.

The important thing here is the `order by` as part of the `over` definition.

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: This query gets all record. It doesnt group and sum the amount

Comment: This works partialy, as the sum by day is not done anymore. I get valid running sum, but if I have two entries by day, the sum is the same amount for those. 
`1|300|2010-01-01`
`2|300|2010-01-01`
`3|600|2010-01-02` 
instead of :
`1|300|2010-01-01`
`2|600|2010-01-02` needless to say this is way over my current sql skills ^^'

Answer (score 1):

That's a running total.

Have a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153879/how-do-i-calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-without-using-a-cursor).  The answer by Quassnoi considers PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I'm not sure I understand what is said there, maybe I'll just use a simpler, but sloppy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select date,(select sum(amount)
                    from mytable11 T1 
                    where T1.date<=T2.date
                    )as cum_sum
from mytable11 T2
group by date
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't manage to adapt your query, it said cum_sum did not exist. The above solution worked though, i'm guessing it's almost the same mechanism as yours.

Comment: `[date]` is not a valid syntax for Postgres

Comment: @Alex: I have done this in sql server, sorry I dont know postgressql

Comment: I know, I just translated my var to english so it's understood on stackoverflow, my real var is not date.